# Rails 4 updating field in devise registrations controller before saving user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to generate and save a random string of characters to a user field called railsid. I have overridden the registrations_controller.rb for the devise user. I would like this randomly generated string of characters to be saved into the user object when the object is created. When I go into the rails console to see if the user has a railsid saved, it returns nil.

registrations_controller.rb

```
class Lenders::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.railsid = '%010d' % rand(10 ** 10)
    super
  end

  def edit
    super
  end 

  def update
    super
  end

  def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_user!", :force => true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_user")
  end

  private

    def update_sanitized_params
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :type, :confirmed_at, :first_name, :last_name, :railsid)}
    end

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      root_path
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after posting this I tried the update_attribute method and it worked perfectly.

```
def create
  super
  resource.update_attribute(:railsid, '%010d' % rand(10 ** 10))
end
```